# Incomplete dataframe for output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am converting my json file to a dataframe in python, but my output is not as expected.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset=pd.read_json(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\a\json\result.json")

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataset, orient='columns')
print(df)
```

This is the output:

```
                  Comments
0   {'name': 'D', 'u...
1   {'name': 'F', 'url': 'https://...
2   {'name': 'G ...
3   {'name': 'E...
4   {'name': 'Y', 'url': 'h...
5   {'name': 'U...
6   {'name': 'V...
```

How can I construct the dataframe with `name`, `url` etc. as columns.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your json as well?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
with open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\a\json\result.json" , encoding="utf8") as f:
     data = json.load(f)
df=pd.DataFrame(data['selection1'][0]['CommentID'])
```

Comment: How do you want ur output to look like?

Comment: can you post a sample of your json data as text not img?

Comment: Hello Sir, the df=pd.DataFrame(data['selection1'][0][CommentID']) is giving me results for only the 1st part, how can I have for the whole dataset?